# Recalculate fitting parameters after period of time loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, apply, curve-fitting

I have a dataframe similar to the one shown below and was wondering how I can loop through and calculate fitting parameters every set number of days. For example, I would like to be able to input 30 days and have be able to get new constants for the first 30 days, then the first 60 days and so on until the end of the date range.

```
ID    date     amount delta_t
1   2020/1/1    10.2     0
1   2020/1/2    11.2     1
2   2020/1/1    12.3     0
2   2020/1/2    13.3     1
```

I would like to have the parameters stored in another dataframe which is what I am currently doing for the entire dataset but that is over the whole time period rather than n day blocks. Then using the constants for each set period I will calculate the graph points and plot them.

Right now I am using groupby to group the wells by ID then using the apply method to calculate the constants for each ID. This works for the entire dataframe but the constants will change if I am only using 30 day periods.

I don't know if there is a way in the apply method to more easily do this and output the constants either to a new column or a seperate dataframe that is one row per ID. Any input is greatly appreciated.

```
def parameters(x):
        variables, _ = curve_fit(expo, x['delta_t'], x['amount'])
        return pd.Series({'param1': variables[0], 'param2': variables[1], 'param3': variables[2]})
param_series = df_filt.groupby('ID').apply(parameters)
```